# Google Analytics 4 / Custom dimension with multiple values per event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Im trying to extend Google Analytics 4 reports with data from the contact form submission.

Im sending event with a custom data through `dataLayer` to Google Tag Manager. Then GTM sends this to Google Analytics 4.

```js
window.dataLayer.push({
 event: 'formSubmission',
 formData: {
  lead_name: 'Lorem',
  lead_email: 'lorem@ipsum.com',
  lead_areas: ['web app design', 'mobile development']
 }
});
```

I've correctly registered all custom dimensions and my data proceed correctly.

However, when im trying to create the report using `lead_areas`, Im facing a trouble that my areas listed as a string with comma-separated values instead of single values.
[image]

I don't have much experience in GA4. Please help me understand,

How can I send **multiple values for one custom dimension** in the scope of single event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two type of custom parameters: text or number. So you can't send an array as value of a parameter but you can send different parameters like lead_area1, lead_area2, etc...

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I've ended with using custom metrics according to this article - https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/07/14/report-multiple-categories-custom-metrics-google-analytics/. 
Basically, I've created custom metric for each area. This way i can easily use this data in my custom reports.

Comment: @Michele Pisani What if you were to use multiple event pushes?  Would it keep all that data?

Comment: You will have as many events as you have sent.